# EaselJS Spritesheets from TexturePacker

Tags: json, easeljs, createjs, sprite-sheet, texturepacker

How do you create proper spritesheet exports for EaselJS from TexturePacker? After exporting I get something like this ...

```
{
"images": ["textures.png"],
"frames": [
    [818, 44, 42, 42], 
    [818, 1, 42, 42], 
    [775, 87, 42, 42], 
    [775, 44, 42, 42], 
    [775, 1, 42, 42], 
    [732, 87, 42, 42], 
    [732, 44, 42, 42], 
    [732, 1, 42, 42], 
    [689, 87, 42, 42], 
    [689, 44, 42, 42]
],
"animations": {
        "load_indicator_01":[0], 
        "load_indicator_02":[1], 
        "load_indicator_03":[2], 
        "load_indicator_04":[3], 
        "load_indicator_05":[4], 
        "load_indicator_06":[5], 
        "load_indicator_07":[6], 
        "load_indicator_08":[7], 
        "load_indicator_09":[8], 
        "load_indicator_10":[9]
},
"texturepacker": [
        "SmartUpdateHash: $TexturePacker:SmartUpdate:9148c4d9cc1b277627212fb0bffcda4d:fabda013c371507b8fb93d52f15735a0:205920eec6ac5ad8b6794732cd49ae1d$",
        "Created with TexturePacker (http://www.texturepacker.com) for EaselJS"
]
}
```

Every frame is defined as an animation which is pointless. Is this exporter just a joke or how can I export for EaselJS properly? Any trick involved?

Answer (score 1):

basically its the format easeljs ask for a [spritesheet](http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/SpriteSheet.html)
you would do the next:

```
$.getJSON("sprites.json", function(json) {
    spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet(json);
});
```

and create a variable for each frame, in your case:

```
var load_indicator_01 = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet, "load_indicator_01");
```

to automate i made this snippet:

```
var spriteSheet;
var sprites = {}
$.getJSON("sprites.json", function(json) {
    spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet(json);
    for(var sprite in json.animations){
        sprites[sprite] = new createjs.Sprite(spriteSheet, sprite);
    }
});
```

`

Answer (score 1):

TexturePacker is capable of generating a .json file with the correct "animations" object to pass to the EaselJS SpriteSheet constructor. In your example, it would look like this:

```
"animations": {
  "load_indicator": { "frames": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] }
},
```

However, two things need to be true in order for the correct .json information to be auto-generated.

- Your image sequence files must have a hyphen - or underscore _ right before the frame numbering (e.g. "load_indicator_00.png" but not "load_indicator00.png").
- You must have "Auto-detect animations" checked in the TexturePacker settings.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not a joke. The feature of exporting to EaselJS/CreateJS json format is indeed exist.

You can follow these steps:

1. There is a **Data Format** switch button ([Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvGbo.jpg)) in the settings panel.
2. Click the button and select **EaselJS / CreateJS** in the long list.
3. Next to the Data Format button, set the output file path at **JSON file** textbox.
4. Publish sprite sheet and you will get it.

My version is TexturePacker 4.0.2 on Windows